# looking for a jquery virtual keyboard where i can navigate to the different letters with the arrow keys

Tags: jquery, keyboard, cursor, virtual

i am looking for a out of the box solution for a jquery based virtual keyboard like:

- http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery/

where it is possible to navigate to each key with the cursor arrow keys.

normally you would select each letter by moving the mouse over it and enter it in the text box by pressing the mouse button, but in my case i want to use a tv remote control like:

- http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Generic-remote-control-shallow-focus.jpg

so its only:

- all numbers 0-9
- cursor keys arrow up, down, left, right
- ok/enter button

i would like to navigate to the char i want to enter with the cursor keys and add it to the textarea by pressing the ok/enter button.

does anybody now a ready to go / out of the box solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this functionality to the [Keyboard](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard) plugin as an extension in version 1.8.14 and improved upon in version 1.8.14.2.

Just follow the instructions in the [wiki documentation](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/Setup) to add the navigation extension :)